# Highlight (select) DataGridRow based on object property in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, datagrid, esri

For context, I'm looking to replicate the FeatureDataGrid implemented by ESRI for a map visualization app. Using MVVM, I have bound the map and data to an observable collection of DataPoints. Each DataPoint has an IsSelected property, which is toggled when you change the associated checkbox in the datagrid, or if you click the map graphic that represents it.

I'd like to remove the IsSelected CheckBoxColumn from the datagrid, and instead change the IsSelected property of a DataPoint by simply selecting it in the datagrid.

Selecting something in the datagrid would change IsSelected, which should be reflected on the map automatically by a change in color/size of the graphic. Conversely, selecting objects in the map should make them highlighted in the datagrid.

Is this possible? Where should I begin?

Here are some attempts that did not work:

```
        <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="datagrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="400" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <sdk:DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </Style>
            </sdk:DataGrid.RowStyle>
        </sdk:DataGrid>
```

and

```
        <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="datagrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="400" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

To be clear, the map is bound to the collection and isn't an important part of this question--**I'm simply looking for a way to bind the IsSelected property of a DataPoint to the DataGridRow's highlighted/selected state.**

Let me know if more information would be useful.

**EDIT**

I've found a solution that I believe violates MVVM and adds some (hopefully) unnecessary logic. Perhaps someone more knowledgable with MVVM could comment and convince me otherwise, or confirm my inclination:

Putting this in the code behind:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Messenger.Default.Register<DataPointSelectedMessage>(this, DataPointSelectedChange);
    }

    private void DataPointSelectedChange(DataPointSelectedMessage msg)
    {
        if (datagrid.SelectedItems.Contains(msg.Content))
        {
            datagrid.SelectedItems.Remove(msg.Content);
        }
        else
        {
            datagrid.SelectedItems.Add(msg.Content);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 2**

I'm still new to silverlight. Turns out ListBox does the behavior I'm looking for by default. Here is the related code for anyone who runs into this:

```
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Multiple">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}"/>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
```

I would still be interested to get input on implementing this with a datagrid, however. I may end up needing some datagrid features.

Thanks.